# Errors in AVCONV (error count , error y=31 x=16, overread 8 )

Tags: avconv

I have a Dlink camera DCS-932L.

I want to get video -> image.

To do that I execute:

```
avconv -i http://user:pass@[IP]/video.cgi?user=user&password=pass&channel=0&.mjpg "%d.jpeg"
```

A few times I get errors like:

```
[mjpeg @ 0x18a1240] error y=31 x=16
```

or

```
error count: 64
```

or

```
overread 8
```

Is there a way to discard this errors? If I have a bad image doesn't matter. I want that `avconv` to continues with saving images.